# Can't receive data on pull socket using zeroMQ, "Address in use" - Error

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq

I currently try to set up a plain Push-Pull-Socket architecture using zeroMQ whereas Metatrader 4 (MQL) acts as `publisher` and my Python backend acts as `consumer`.

I push data from Metatrader 4 terminal every second which works just fine. However, **I'm having tough times to receive data on the pull socket**. Once I try to pull that data out of the wire the atom `script` package raises the error `address already in use`.

I run both the MT 4 terminal and the Python script on my local machine while in development.

**Metatrader 4:**

```
extern string PROJECT_NAME = "Dashex.Feeder";
extern string ZEROMQ_PROTOCOL = "tcp";
extern string HOSTNAME = "*";
extern int PUSH_PORT = 32220;

extern string t0 = "--- Feeder Parameters ---";
input string DID = "insert your DID here";
extern string t1 = "--- ZeroMQ Configuration ---";
extern bool Publish_MarketData = false;

// ZeroMQ environment //

// CREATE ZeroMQ Context
Context context(PROJECT_NAME);

// CREATE ZMQ_PUSH SOCKET
Socket pushSocket(context, ZMQ_PUSH);

string Publish_Symbols[7] = {
   "EURUSD","GBPUSD","USDJPY","USDCAD","AUDUSD","NZDUSD","USDCHF"
};

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

int OnInit()
  {
//---

   EventSetTimer(1);     // Set Millisecond Timer to get client socket input

   context.setBlocky(false);

   // Send responses to PULL_PORT that client is listening on.
   Print("[PUSH] Connecting MT4 Server to Socket on Port " + IntegerToString(PUSH_PORT) + "..");
   pushSocket.connect(StringFormat("%s://%s:%d", ZEROMQ_PROTOCOL, HOSTNAME, PUSH_PORT));

   pushSocket.setSendHighWaterMark(1);
   pushSocket.setLinger(0);   

//---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{
//---

   Print("[PUSH] Disconnecting MT4 Server from Socket on Port " + IntegerToString(PUSH_PORT) + "..");
   pushSocket.disconnect(StringFormat("%s://%s:%d", ZEROMQ_PROTOCOL, HOSTNAME, PUSH_PORT));

   // Shutdown ZeroMQ Context
   context.shutdown();
   context.destroy(0);

   EventKillTimer();
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTimer()
{
   /*
      Use this OnTimer() function to send market data to consumer.
   */
   if(!IsStopped() && Publish_MarketData == true)
   {
      for(int s = 0; s < ArraySize(Publish_Symbols); s++)
      {
         // Python clients can subscribe to a price feed by setting
         // socket options to the symbol name. For example:

         string _tick = GetBidAsk(Publish_Symbols[s]);
         Print("Sending " + Publish_Symbols[s] + " " + _tick + " to PUSH Socket");
         ZmqMsg reply(StringFormat("%s %s", Publish_Symbols[s], _tick));
         pushSocket.send(reply, true);
      }
   }
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

string GetBidAsk(string symbol) {

   MqlTick last_tick;

   if(SymbolInfoTick(symbol,last_tick))
   {
       return(StringFormat("%f;%f", last_tick.bid, last_tick.ask));
   }

   // Default
   return "";
}
```

**Pushing data works as intended:**

[image]

**Python based pull socket:**

```
import zmq
import time

context = zmq.Context()
zmq_socket = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
zmq_socket.bind("tcp://*:32220")
time.sleep(1)

while True:
    result = zmq_socket.recv()
    print(result)
    time.sleep(1)
```

**This is what `script` reports in the console:**

[image]

**Netstat output:**

[image]

Note: When I terminate both the Metatrader push script and the python script the port is still marked as "listened" in netstats. When I change the port to 32225 (or any other) in both instances and re-run them, I get the same error again. If I first run the pull instance I have a sandglass popping up in atom `script`, when I then run the MT4 push instance nothing happens on the pull side. When I then re-run the pull instance I get the same error again.

**Update:**

The `python.exe` instance in the background occupied the port. I shut down the python execution and the port was released again. When I now run my pull instance i receive the following console feedback:

**1.)**

[image]

**2.)**

I then run the push instance which works just fine.

**3.)**

The pull instance still shows the sandglass and doesn't print any data into the console:

[image]

**4.)**

When I then re-run the pull instance it raises the error **address in use** which now makes sense since Python uses that port still in the background.

**But why isn't any data printed on the pull side?** Do I have to change the pull client code in order to be able to "grab" the pushed data?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that there isn't something already listening on port `32200`? I thought at first that maybe the error was due to a socket still in the `TIME_WAIT` state, but a I can run the equivalent of your receiver several times in a row without an error.

Comment: I now have the Push socket pushing data on port `32200` and the pull socket binding to the same socket. But instead of printing results on the pull side it tells me that `address is in use` (Added netstats pic). I am sure that nothing else listens on port 32220 since I do only launch the push and pull instances after rebooting, no else programs and such.

Comment: @larsks I updated the initial post. I solved the port problem, but can't "see" the pushed data on the pull side. Do I need to change the pull instance code wise in order to "grab" the pushed data and print it to the console? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `PUSH` code, here:

```
extern string HOSTNAME = "*";
```

While you can legitimately use `*` for the hostname component in a `bind` URL (in which case it means "listen on all addresses"), it doesn't make any sense in a `connect` call: you must provide a valid hostname or ip address.

If you were to modify your code to read:

```
extern string HOSTNAME = "localhost";
```

It would probably work as expected.

Here's a simple Python `PUSH` client I used to test your `PULL` code; if you run this and run your `PULL` code (as posted in your question), it all works:

```
import time
import zmq

c = zmq.Context()
s = c.socket(zmq.PUSH)

s.connect('tcp://localhost:32220')

i = 0
while True:
    s.send_string('this is message {}'.format(i))
    i += 1
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enable allow trading in metatrader terminal:
`tools > options > expert advisor`

[image: screen-shot]